# Is $f(a)-f(b) \approx f^{\prime}(b)(a-b)$ for small differences and if so, why?

Tags: calculus, logic

As in the question, I asked myself whether $f(a)-f(b) \approx f^{\prime}(b)(a-b)$ holds true for small differences between a and b and if so, why that is the case. Thanks for every hint.

Comment: That is just because the limit, as $a$ tends to $b$, of $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$ is precisely $f'(b)$, by definition.

Comment: The key idea of calculus is to approximate a function locally with a linear function: $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$. The *fundamental strategy of calculus* is to replace a complicated nonlinear function $f$ with its local linear approximation. This simplifies calculations greatly, and the approximation is good enough that the result is often useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $a=b+h$ and define $\epsilon(h)=f’(b)-\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$ then $\epsilon(h)$ goes to $0$ when $h$ goes to $0$. In particular $f(b+h)=f(b)+hf’(b)+\underbrace{h\epsilon(h)}_{\text{error term}}$ which is exactly what you stated.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable, then, on a small enough scale it can be approximately a line.

In which case $f(x+\delta) \approx f(x) + \delta f'(x)$ for small $\delta$

We could also invoke the mean value theorem.

There exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$

Answer (score 2):

If $f'$ is assumed to be bounded then $f(a)-f(b)=f'(t) (a-b)$ for some $t \in (a,b)$ so $|f'(t) (a-b)-f'(b) (a-b)|\leq 2M|a-b|$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f'|$.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer, since op never said to assume $f'$ bounded

Comment: This error bound is **so** loose that it’s a significant stretch to describe this as “approximately”.  It’s like saying that 310 is approximately equal to 100 because it’s only 210 away.  And it doesn’t improve asymptotically as $a$ approaches $b$.

Answer (score 2):

That is essentially Taylor's theorem:

$\begin{align*}
f(x)
   &= f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + R_1(x)
\end{align*}$

Here $R_1(x)$ is the residue, which for functions with continuous second derivative tends to zero as $x$ tends to $a$ (thus the error is small for $x$ near $a$).

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful to state precisely what you are assuming and what you want to be true.  One interpretation of the statement might be that if $f$ is a differentiable function on an interval $(c,d)$ (or maybe on the whole real line $\mathbb R$), for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $c < a < b < d$ with
$0 < b-a < \epsilon$, $1-\epsilon < \dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{f'(b)(b-a)} < 1+\epsilon$.
  But that's not true: for example you'll run into trouble if $f'(b)$ can be $0$.